# How do I get "Fable: The Lost Chapter" working with Wine?

Tags: 11.04, wine, games

I would like to play "Fable: The Lost Chapter". But I don't know how to set up wine and playonlinux in Ubuntu. I played Fable: The Lost Chapter in Windows XP but I decided to switch to Ubuntu, and really miss that game now.

if you would be so kind to explain step by step what I need to do to play it.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Wine app database](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=3827), seems like this game would run if you install a couple of libraries. According to one of the comments in that page, you have to install libraries using this command:

```
winetricks vcrun6 wmp9 quartz devenum d3dx9_36
```

After that, you should be able to run the game. Also, those instructions should work for wine 1.3.5 (or later). During game play, the report says you should skip videos.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

I would use playonlinux. It is essentially wine but has custom scripts that fix common faults with specific applications. Fable gets 4.5/5 stars too so that looks pretty good.

http://www.playonlinux.com/repository/?script=15