# Download and install Fable the lost chapters on ubuntu 20.4

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

Hi I have a HP 250 g5 pretty old laptop and being sick of windows I decided to install a Linux dist specifically Ubuntu on it and since then I have never thought of ever going back. I wanted to install an old game I used to play Fable the lost chapters and was looking for a way of how to and stumbled upon the following forums:
1.

[How do I get "Fable: The Lost Chapter" working with Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102101/how-do-i-get-fable-the-lost-chapter-working-with-wine)

2.

https://www.gamersonlinux.com/forum/threads/fable-the-lost-chapters-guide.167/

On the first post you just get redirected to Playonlinux and Wine and not a lot instructions are given at least to me, while on the second post the instruction are clear enough but how to get the files for disk 1 and 2 are not explained.

I tried installing it with Playonlinux and still am but something goes wrong (will still try) thought to ask if there might be a simple way such as running scripts and if so could anyone paste the scripts to run XD

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2knCF.png)

Comment: The guides assumes you own the CDs. Wine is just the "emulator", the software that allows running a few Windows programs; PoL is just a tool to Manage containers and different Wine versions and also has a database of additional installations required for some software. NEITHER contains or have access to the software itself, user must provide those .

Comment: oooooooo now it's clear thank you so much man your explanation is awesome and you're awesome I hope I still have the disk XD